# MySQL time field type conversion issue with AWS DMS

Tags: mysql, replication, aws, time, amazon-dms

I have a DB MySQL v5.6 community edition as a source DB and AWS RDS MySQL v5.7 as target in AWS DMS and have an issue with time field type. DMS task is full load and replication. During full load all time fields values are migrated correctly, but during ongoing replication/CDC all time field values are converted to either 00:00:00 or 23:59:59. Probably the source of the issue is in bin log used for replication, but I need help in solving that.
Conversions are like this:

```
00:52:19  -> 00:00:00
02:39:08  -> 00:00:00
00:25:56  -> 23:59:59
00:33:01  -> 23:59:59
00:22:51  -> 23:59:59
00:30:26  -> 23:59:59
06:00:52  -> 23:59:59
```

MySQL 5.6

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_routes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vrijeme` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9702 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

AWS RDS MySQL 5.7:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_routes` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `vrijeme` time NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9702 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Comment: Please post table schemas